# cronjob: curl to scrape website and run command if down

Tags: php, curl, cron

Context:
Server1 hosts a website.
Server2 hosts a cronjob.

Problem:
I would like Server2's cronjob to check if the website hosted on Server1 is down. I want it to be done through scraping the web page's content. If "hello welcome to server1.com" is missing then it's down.

For example, the cronjob on Server2 should look like:

```
curl --silent http://server1.com | if !match "<h1>hello welcome</h1>" | ssh -p 22 root@server1.com 'my command1; my command2; etc;'
```

I need a way to parse the webpage's content + an "if" condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current logic as nobody could help: Server2 hosts a php page cURLing server1.com. The cronjob on Server2 runs the php page every minute. If server1.com is down, the php page generates a bash script with the commands to execute. So there's a second cronjob on Server2 that also runs the bash script every minute (bash script is populated with the commands if server1.com is down, or is empty if server1.com is live). Hope it helps. If you have a more elegant solution I'd still take it though.